# GitHub action not read other mine github action yaml file

Tags: github, github-actions

My plan would be to use some GH actions YAML file in my other action YAML file.

I have a `list_images.yaml` file in my repo: `.github/workflows` folder. This action looks like this:

```
name: List Docker Images
on: [push]

jobs:
  list_images:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: List Docker images
        run: docker images
```

It just list the built images in a runner...

I have another action YAML file, this checks out my source code, builds an image, tags it. To test how I an use one of my action YAML file in another action YAML file, I added `list_images.yaml` file usage in this way:

```
name: Try to build image and push it into ghcr.io

on:
    push:  
        branches:
            - GhActions_test
    workflow_dispatch: 

jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            - name: checkout app source code
              uses: actions/checkout@v4
            - name: Where I am
              run: pwd
              shell: bash
            - name: List current folder
              run: ls -la
              shell: bash
            - name: List workflows
              run: ls -la ./.github/workflows
              shell: bash
            - name: Build image
              run: docker compose --env-file .env.prod build app_base
            - name: tag image
              run: docker tag app:latest ghcr.io/my_org/app:1.0.0
            - name: List Docker images
              uses: ./.github/workflows/list_images.yaml            
            - name: Login to Docker Hub
              uses: docker/login-action@v3
              with:
                registry: ghcr.io
                username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
                password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}              
            - name: Push image to GuitHub package repo
              run: docker push ghcr.io/my_org/app:latest
```

My problem is, that I got an error message when I want to use my list_images.yaml file:

```
> Error: Can't find 'action.yml', 'action.yaml' or 'Dockerfile' under
> '/home/runner/work/my_repo/my_repo/.github/actions/list_images.yaml'.
> Did you forget to run actions/checkout before running your local
> action?
```

I really don't understand why not find the `list_imgaes.yaml` file, how ever it placed next to the caller action YAML file. The result of some steps:

1. Where I am: /home/runner/work/my_repo/my_repo
2. List workflows:

   ```
   drwxr-xr-x 2 runner docker 4096 Feb 20 09:34 .
   drwxr-xr-x 4 runner docker 4096 Feb 20 09:34 ..
   -rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker 1976 Feb 20 09:34 build_try.yaml
   -rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker  156 Feb 20 09:34 list_images.yaml
   ```

Any idea what's wrong?
I know, I can put the list docker images command into the "main" action YAML file, but this is just a learning step.

Comment: Hi @jonrsharpe! Could you tell me, why did you edit my question? Why need it? I don't think, that is your task...and did you add -1 to the question?
Next time please leave my question alone and not edit them! Thanks for that!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: You're using a workflow as a [custom action](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions) i.e. `uses: ./.github/workflows/list_images.yaml` that's why it's complaining about `action.yml`, `action.yaml`, and `Dockerfile`; and the path they should be under i.e. `.github/actions`. See [Reusing workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/reusing-workflows) on how to reuse existing workflows.

Comment: Thanks Azeem! I am just find the same documentation on GH and start to read it. Not exactly clear...not now, but I hope it will :)

Comment: I add here as a comment, that I understood, that call an action from another action is possible, but it mostly looks like...the easiest way to call it in another job (=runner)...but what I want...maybe I can say...as a real injection? Job start, do steps, and suddenly call other action steps...then continue with default action steps...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a composite action instead of a reusable workflow. They execute as part of the same job.

More information [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/creating-a-composite-action)

Answer (score -1):

Reading a lot, do a tons of research...the result and my understanding is: it is not possible to use any kind of custom (=created by you) action to call it in a job. Reusable is possible in a new job, and it is also not possible to run 2 or more jobs on the same runner, except if the runner is a custom runner...

Comment: If you have an action in the same repo, you can call it by its relative path in any of your workflows e.g. `- uses: ./.github/actions/some-action`.